# SQL query to get course name along with the mac marks and student name

Tags: sql

I have a table of student which include S_Id , Name , Subject , Marks. I want to get a Course Name with Its Highest Marks and Student Name who got that marks.

The Query I wrote for this is

```sql
SELECT Subject,max(Marks) 
from Student 
group by(subject)
```

Now What If I also want to get student name who got that marks. What should be the query.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; your indoor voice is fine, thank you. Also, please don't tag conflicting RDBMS unless the question is really regarding both. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from student s
where s.marks = (select max(s2.marks) from student s2 where s2.subject = s.subject);
```

This will return all students that have the highest marks for a subject when there are duplicates.